# SSH: connection refused to wlan, works when i plug wired lan and unplug

Tags: ssh, wifi

If i do:

```
ssh 192.168.1.8 //my wlan0 connection
```

i get:

```
ssh: connect to host 192.168.1.8 port 22: Connection refused
```

However, if i plug the LAN, i can ssh to 192.168.1.7 (wired ip). And after that, i can ssh to 192.168.1.8 (wlan0 port) with no issues even after unplugging lan.

What can it be?

Drawing:

[image]

Comment: Usually it helps if you set the option "devices can connect each other" in the wlan router.

Comment: are the 2 interfaces bridged, as they are on the same subnet?

Comment: sshd started before wifi interface was up.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like ssh isn't listening on all interfaces or is administratively blocked (iptables rule for example).

Start by making sure that `sshd` is listening on all interfaces. Go to the server you are trying to connect to and run:

```
sudo lsof -n -i -P | grep sshd
```

This is ls for open files. The flags are `-n` => don't bother looking up ip names (this makes lsof return faster), `-i` => list all Internet network files, and `-P` => don't bother looking up port names. Then we look only for the ssh daemon using `grep`.

You should get something like:

```
sshd       1472        root    3u  IPv4 4972775      0t0  TCP *:22 (LISTEN)
sshd       1472        root    4u  IPv6 4972777      0t0  TCP *:22 (LISTEN)
```

Here sshd is listening on TPC port 22 for all ip addresses  (`*:22`).

Next check for iptables rules:

```
sudo iptables -L -n
```

This is list (`-L`) the rules and again don't look up names (`-n`).

One of these is most likely the problem.

Comment: 1. yes, i got 0t0  TCP *:22 (LISTEN).
2. I use UFW, and port 22 is allowed: 22/tcp ALLOW       Anywhere

Comment: Try temporarily disabling UFW completely. Also, what does sshd log: (try `sudo journalctl _COMM=sshd`)?